# Wrong URL when consuming existing Java REST API using rails ActiveResource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, rest, activeresource

I am new to ruby on rails.I am trying to consume my existing Java REST api using Rails, ActiveResource class, but every time resource URL hit, is wrong (`https://myapp/resource/**apis**/responce.json`), where the correct url is (`https://myapp/resource/**api**/responce.json`)

Problem is active resource mapping apis/ instead of api/

**Below is my code for model => app/model/api.rb**

```
class Api < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "https://myapp/resource"
  self.format = :json
  self.element_name = "api"
end
```

**Code in app/controllers/api_controller.rb**

```
@api = Api.get(:responce, :key => "key", :userId =>'1')
```

The above code always give 404 error, when I check the logs, resource is hitting `https://myapp/resource/**apis**/responce.json?key=key&userId=1`
Where it must hit resource URL as `https://myapp/resource/**api**/responce.json`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `self.element_name = "api"` is fixing the pluralization when you are doing a find(:first) or similar.  What you need is `self.collection_name = "api"`.  That should fix the URL it is creating.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! 
It will be great help if you can suggest me any books, to learn Ruby on Rails, JRuby, RSpen to become professional